# How do I write a literal quotation mark when using the formatting macros?

Tags: rust, formatting

I need to create a JSON file with some simple data, but the Rust compiler doesn't recognize `" "` as symbols in `file.write_all(b" !HERE! ");`. These are necessary in JSON syntax. I tried `r#""#` but it also doesn't work.

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let mut file = File::create("model.json").expect("fail creating file");

    file.write_all(b"!HERE!").expect("fail writing data");
}
```

Is there a solution for this issue?

Comment: Please, put the failing code. Without it, we can only guess what is your issue.

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=b3a70ab3e3dd4588240e1937484a865f

Comment: An empty string slice, aka `""` is totaly legit. `let a = "";` will work! However, if you try to do something like `let a = """"` it will not work in any language I know of. You have to escape the inner quotations with `\ `, e.g. `let a = "\"\"";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your original approach is correct:

```
let mut file = File::create("model.json").expect("fail creating file");
let json = r#"{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}"#;
file.write_all(json.as_bytes()).expect("fail writing data");
```